# Why is Kubo's eye injury crucial to the plot? Is it symbolic of something?

Tags: plot-explanation, kubo-and-the-two-strings

I watched 'Kubo and the Two Strings' with my five-year old, and when it ended I was thoroughly confused.

Very early in the movie, we learn that Kubo is blind in one eye.

Why is this crucial to the plot? Is it symbolic of something?

I'm asking because I do not think that this plot decision was made without cost. I think this made the movie seem much more violent. It matters to me because I thought this movie was made for young kids.

Comment: what made you think it was for young kids?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, Kubo missing an eye is crucial to the plot.

His mother sacrificed her immortality when she fell in love with Hanzo. Most of the movie is her and Hanzo (in his beetle form) protecting Kubo from their family (Raiden, The Moon King, Karasu and Washi the two sisters) who want to take his other eye.

His grandfather Raiden, the Moon King, wants both of Kubo's eyes so that he would be blind to the "earthly" world around him.  Essentially making him blind to his humanity, awakening his heavenly heritage and thus making Kubo an immortal.  This way he could join his Grandfather up in the Heavens.

Comment: And also at the very end, we see that after he's defeated and loses his memories the moon king still has the eye he took from Kubo and is able to use it to see like a human and become part of human society

Answer (score 2):

What's the symbolic meaning of the eyes in the film? Kubo loses his and his other is a crucial plot point. Both his grandfather and mother have scars across opposite eyes. Monkey has a scratch under one but it's the opposite eye to Kubos mum so I wasn't sure whether that's just a hint to her real identity or another reference to eyes being key. 
I also gathered that the moon acted as the moon gods eye and that was why Kubo couldn't go out at night.

Comment: What does this add to the previous answer.